# strtok function c element considered problem

Tags: c, split, substring, c-strings

When I try to split a string with a delimiter, the `strtok` function doesn't consider empty strings and I would like to know how to fix it.
For example, in my case, I have to split strings like `"a-b-c"`. When I try to split the string `"a--b-c"`, the result should be `"a"`, `""`, `"b"`, `"c"` (note the empty string). But if I print the result of each element after calling the function, it only considers `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

```
    char str[] = "a--b-c";
    char *delim = "-";
    char *token;

    token = strtok(str, delim);

    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("element is: =====%s===== \n ", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
```

Elements printed should be 4 (`a`, empty string, `b`, `c`) but with this code, it's only 3 (`a`, `b`, `c`).

Comment: (1) `strtok` modifies its argument but you cannot modify a string literal. (2) `strtok` never produces an empty token.

Comment: From the Linux man page: "The  strtok()  function  breaks a string into a sequence of zero or more **nonempty** tokens"

Answer (score 6):

According to the C standard, the first action of `strtok()` is that it

> searches the string pointed to by `s1` for the first character that is *not*
> contained in the current separator string pointed to by `s2`.

If you want different behaviour, you'll need to write your own function that does what you want.

Answer (score 5):

The function `strtok` searches for the first character that is not contained in the current separator string. So adjacent separator characters are skipped.

Also the function changes the source string.

Instead of using `strtok` you can use another string function as for example `strcspn`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "a--b-c";
    const char *delim = "-";

    for (char *p = str; *p != '\0'; )
    {
        size_t n = strcspn( p, delim );

        printf( "\"%.*s\"\n", ( int )n, p );

        if ( *( p += n ) != '\0') ++p;
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
"a"
""
"b"
"c"
```

If for a string like that `"-"` you need to output two substrings like

```
""
""
```

or for a string like that `"a--b-c-"` you need to output

```
"a"
""
"b"
"c"
""
```

then it is enough to make the following minor changes in the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "a--b-c-";
    const char *delim = "-";

    for (char *p = str; *p != '\0'; )
    {
        size_t n = strcspn( p, delim );

        printf( "\"%.*s\"\n", ( int )n, p );

        if (*( p += n ) != '\0')
        {
            if (*++p == '\0')
            {
                printf( "\"%s\"\n", p );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program output in this case is

```
"a"
""
"b"
"c"
""
```

For each gotten substring pointed to by the pointer `p` and with the length `n` you could either define a variable length character array or dynamically allocate a character array and then copy the substring in the array if it is required. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "a--b-c";
    const char *delim = "-";

    for (char *p = str; *p != '\0'; )
    {
        size_t n = strcspn( p, delim );

        char substr[n + 1];

        memcpy( substr, p, n );
        substr[n] = '\0';
             
        printf( "\"%s\"\n", substr );

        if ( *( p += n ) != '\0') ++p;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Leonardo Should "a-b-" produce 2 lines of output or 3?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I would ask should "-" produce two substrings or only one?

Comment: IMO, given `N` occurrences of `'-'`, there should be `N+1` substrings to meet OP's not-quite-clear goal.

Comment: You can avoid the need for a local copy with `printf("\"%.*s\"\n", (int)n, p);`

Answer (score 2):

The function `strtok` will not give you any empty tokens. If you want to change that behavior, you will have you write your own `strtok` function, which is not that hard. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *my_strtok( char *str, const char *delim )
{
    //this pointer will always point to the next token to
    //be processed and returned, or NULL if we have already
    //returned the last token
    static char *next;

    char *p;

    if ( str == NULL )
    {
        //check whether we have already returned the last
        //token
        if ( next == NULL )
        {
            //we already returned the last token in a
            //previous function call, so return NULL to
            //indicate that there are no more tokens
            return NULL;
        }

        //the next token is available, so process it
        str = next;
    }

    //find the next delimiter character
    p = strpbrk( str, delim );

    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        //this is the last token, so remember that there are
        //no more tokens
        next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        //there are more tokens available, so write a null
        //terminating character at the end of the current
        //token and remember the start of the next token
        *p = '\0';
        next = p + 1;
    }

    //return the token
    return str;
}

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "a--b-c";
    char *delim = "-";
    char *token;

    token = my_strtok(str, delim);

    while ( token != NULL )
    {
        printf( "Found token: \"%s\"\n", token );
        token = my_strtok( NULL, delim );
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Found token: "a"
Found token: ""
Found token: "b"
Found token: "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` does not work the way you expect. The specification for this function is clear: all sequences of characters from the delimiter string form single delimiters and initial and trailing delimiters are consumed without producing tokens. Therefore `strtok()` never produces empty tokens.

The rationale for this is the original purpose of this function: to split words separated by whitespace.  Passing a separator string of `" \t\f\r\n\v"` achieves this goal and it is rather intuitive that sequences of white space characters be considered a single separator.

The behavior you describe corresponds to the `strsep()` function originally developed for the BSD Unix variant and available on most Unix platforms, including linux.  Here is an abstract from the manual page:

> **NAME**
>
> `strsep` - separate strings
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `strsep()` function locates, in the string referenced by `*stringp`, the first occurrence of any character in the string `delim` (or the terminating `'\0'` character) and replaces it with a `'\0'`.  The location of the next character after the delimiter character (or `NULL`, if the end of the string was reached) is stored in `*stringp`.  The original value of `*stringp` is returned.
>
> An "empty" field (i.e., a character in the string `delim` occurs as the first character of `*stringp`) can be detected by comparing the location referenced by the returned pointer to `'\0'`.
>
> If `*stringp` is initially `NULL`, `strsep()` returns `NULL`.

Contrary to `strtok()`, this function does not store a context in a static variable, so it is thread safe and reentrant, it can be used in nested loops. It is also easier to use in loops as all calls in the sequence have the same arguments.

If this function is not available on your platform, you can use this definition:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim) {
    char *start = *stringp;
    if (start) {
        /* skip all characters in the token (not delimiters) */
        char *p = start + strcspn(start, delim);
        if (*p) {
            *p++ = '\0';
            *stringp = p;
        } else {
            *stringp = NULL;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

Here is a modified version of your test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "a--b-c";
    const char *delim = "-";
    char *token;
    char *ctx = str;

    while ((token = strsep(&ctx, delim)) != NULL) {
        printf("element is: >>>%s<<<\n", token);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
element is: >>>a<<<
element is: >>><<<
element is: >>>b<<<
element is: >>>c<<<
```