# strtok shifts by one place when encountering a null character

Tags: c, strtok

When I read data from a string with data that is separated with commas using `strtok`, the value that is being read is shifted if the value that was read before was (null).

```c
int main(void)
{ 
    char Temp[10] = "1,2,3,,4";
    
    printf("%s\n", strtok(Temp, ","));
    printf("%s\n", strtok(NULL, ","));
    printf("%s\n", strtok(NULL, ","));
    printf("%s\n", strtok(NULL, ","));
    printf("%s\n", strtok(NULL, ","));
}
```

Expected Output:

```
1
2
3
(null)
4
```

Real Output:

```
1
2
3
4
(null)
```

The same thing happens even if there are 2 blanks. It just moves over twice, rather than once.

Comment: `strtok` is defined to only return a null pointer if there are no more possible results. Therefore your expected output would contradict the definition

Comment: The [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function is specified to skip over empty tokens.

Comment: Besides, if it did work as you expected it to, how would you distinguish between an empty token and the end?

Comment: Hmm. Ya that is fair, I get what you'll are saying but if I need it to output this way, what can I do? because im kinda new to programming and c

Comment: Possible duplicate: [strtok function c element considered problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76430344/12149471)

Comment: A simple string like that is relatively easy to parse. In a loop find the first comma, and get the string up to (but not including) the comma. Skip over the comma, and search for the next comma. Etc.

Comment: If anybody's wondering why it works that way, consider this token argument: `" \r\n\t"`

Answer (score 5):

When `strtok` parses a string, any consecutive delimiter characters will be grouped together.  This basically means that you'll never see a blank token until you reach the end of the string.

The [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) states the following:

> From the above description, it follows that a sequence of two or
> more contiguous delimiter bytes in the parsed string is    considered
> to be a single delimiter, and that delimiter bytes at    the start or
> end of the string are ignored.  Put another way: the    tokens
> returned by `strtok()` are always nonempty strings.  Thus,    for
> example, given the string *"aaa;;bbb,"*, successive calls to    `strtok()`
> that specify the delimiter string `*;,"* would return the    strings
> *"aaa"* and *"bbb"*, and then a null pointer.

So what you're seeing is the expected behavior.

If you want to be able to treat consecutive delimiters as a blank token, you'll need use `strchr` to find each delimiter and copy out the relevant substrings yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The function `strtok` does not have a notion of an empty token. If there is a sequence of more than one delimiter character, it will skip over all of them. This means that in your input, it will skip over any empty fields.

If you want to change that behavior, you will have you write your own `strtok` function, which is not that hard. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *my_strtok( char *restrict str, const char *restrict delim )
{
    //this pointer will always point to the next token to
    //be processed and returned, or NULL if we have already
    //returned the last token
    static char *next;

    char *p;

    if ( str == NULL )
    {
        //check whether we have already returned the last
        //token
        if ( next == NULL )
        {
            //we already returned the last token in a
            //previous function call, so return NULL to
            //indicate that there are no more tokens
            return NULL;
        }

        //the next token is available, so process it
        str = next;
    }

    //find the next delimiter character
    p = strpbrk( str, delim );

    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        //this is the last token, so remember that there are
        //no more tokens
        next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        //there are more tokens available, so write a null
        //terminating character at the end of the current
        //token and remember the start of the next token
        *p = '\0';
        next = p + 1;
    }

    //return the token
    return str;
}

int main( void )
{
    char Temp[] = "1,2,3,,4";
    
    printf( "%s\n", my_strtok( Temp, "," ) );
    printf( "%s\n", my_strtok( NULL, "," ) );
    printf( "%s\n", my_strtok( NULL, "," ) );
    printf( "%s\n", my_strtok( NULL, "," ) );
    printf( "%s\n", my_strtok( NULL, "," ) );
    printf( "%s\n", my_strtok( NULL, "," ) );
}
```

Assuming that you are running a platform on which

```
printf( "%s\n", NULL );
```

prints `(null)` instead of crashing the program, then this program will have the following output:

```
1
2
3

4
(null)
```

Note that the fourth field is now empty.

This answer was partially copied from [a previous answer of mine to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76430520/12149471).

Answer (score 0):

The expected behaviour is the one you observe, and not the one you expect.

`Strtok` is searching for *any number of characters in the provided model* and not only a single char.  The implementation of `strtok` was made to implement the way the shell separates arguments, by means of the `IFS` variable.  Later as quoting was implemented on the shell the use of `strtok` remained, as it was still usefull to separate a string that had spaces, tabs or newlines. You have misinterpreted what `strtok(3)` does, and you need to use `strsep(3)` instead.